# Using "croppie" on front-end / What do I exactly need to do on back-end to actually crop the image?

Tags: node.js, express, croppie

How do I actually crop and compress (resize to snippet size) the image on back-end?

I'm using croppie on front-end: https://foliotek.github.io/Croppie/

I'm completely lost, small guidance would be very helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want crop your pic on back-end? This operation should have be done in browser. When you use `result({ type, size, format, quality, circle })` function, you can get data of **cropped pic**. If type is `base64`, you can save the data to file after `base64_decode` it.